RMI JMXConnectorServer waits two minutes when starting
We run an application on a server with a tomcat frontend. The communicate via RMI.
This setup has worked for many years, but I am having problems setting up a new server. When setting up the MBeanServer for the JMX monitoring the system waits for 2 minutes and 10 seconds.
I have extracted the code into a simple class :
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.management.MBeanServer;
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorServer;
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorServerFactory;
import javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURL;

public class RMITest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int rmiPort = 1199;
        int jmxPort = 5199;
        String hostName = "localhost";

        LocateRegistry.createRegistry(rmiPort);

        MBeanServer mbs = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
        JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi://"+hostName+":"+jmxPort+"/jndi/rmi://"+hostName+":" + rmiPort + "/jmxrmi");
        System.err.println("[RMITest] main - " + url.toString());

        Map<String, Object> envConf = new HashMap<>();
        envConf.put("com.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl", "false");
        envConf.put("com.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate", "false");

        System.err.println("[RMITest] main - Before newJMXConnectorServer" );
        JMXConnectorServer cs = JMXConnectorServerFactory.newJMXConnectorServer(url, envConf, mbs);
        System.err.println("[RMITest] main - Before start" );
        cs.start();
        System.err.println("[RMITest] main - after start" );

        while(true) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}

I launch this using the following Bash script:
#!/bin/sh

/usr/lib/jvm/graalvm21/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file="logging.properties" -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=SERVER_IP RMITest


The java.rmi.server.hostname is important as without that the client will not be able to communicate with the RMI server. However, if I skip this argument I do not get the 2 minute pause in the startup.
I activated the logs in the RMIConnectorServer, using the java.util.logging.config.file argument with these elements changed:
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level     = ALL

javax.management.remote.rmi.level = ALL


The output is :
[RMITest] main - service:jmx:rmi://localhost:5199/jndi/rmi://localhost:1199/jmxrmi
[RMITest] main - Before newJMXConnectorServer
[RMITest] main - Before start
Nov 06, 2024 2:43:16 PM javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer start
FINER: setting default class loader
Nov 06, 2024 2:43:16 PM javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer start
FINER: setting RMIServer object
Nov 06, 2024 2:43:16 PM javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer start
FINER: getting RMIServer object to export
Nov 06, 2024 2:43:16 PM javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer start
FINER: Using external directory: rmi://localhost:1199/jmxrmi
Nov 06, 2024 2:43:16 PM javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer start
FINER: jmx.remote.jndi.rebind=false
Nov 06, 2024 2:43:16 PM javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer start
FINER: binding to rmi://localhost:1199/jmxrmi
Nov 06, 2024 2:45:27 PM javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer start
FINER: Connector Server Address = service:jmx:rmi://localhost:5199/jndi/rmi://localhost:1199/jmxrmi
Nov 06, 2024 2:45:27 PM javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer start
FINER: started.
[RMITest] main - after start

The timestamps show the 2 minute 10 second wait between the binding and the connector server being ready.
Again without the java.rmi.server.hostname argument the process goes straight through.
I cannot find the configuration difference between the two servers (one running Debian 11 one running Debian 12). I have also looked at the DNS configuration and the firewall configuration.
I am currently at a loss where to go from here.

Sorry for the inconvenience. After searching all day the solution came five minutes after I posted the message here.
The problem was the DNS configuration. We had opened the ports in the wrong DNS zone.
As I may not be the only one to have this symptom it may still be useful.
